# What algorithm should i use for this

Tags: algorithm

I need to write a program that will figure out how many children will be able to find a bed to sleep on before it gets dark.

**Each child and each bed has their own set of coordinates (x.x, y.y).**

**Only one child fits one bed.**

**No two children or beds will be at the same set of coordinates.**

**Each child walks one step per minute, so for example it would take 3 minutes for a child to walk from 22.0 , 0.0 to 19.0 , 0.0.**

Example:

> Child1 is at 22.0 , 0.0
>
> Child2 is at 0.0, 19.0
>
> Bed1 is at 18.0 , 0.0
>
> Bed2 is at 50.0, 14.0
>
> It will be dark in 5 minutes, how many children can find a bed within 5 minutes.

I've been looking into the Maximum flow problem but I dont think its applicable to my problem.

Comment: At least give a brute-force solution, so we know you've understood the problem...

Comment: give some kind of code you have tried if you expect anyone to help you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to implement a bipartite maximum matching ( special case of max flow ) algorithm. So first you need to create a graph from your data. Connecting every child to every bed except when the distance of the child to the bed is more than the time that is left till it gets dark. Because bipartite maximum matching is also solvable using max flow, we make a flow network out of this graph and solve it with max flow. For this you should create a `source` node with capacity of `infinity` and connect it to all of the children and also create a `sink` node with `infinity` capacity and connect every bed to it. Also assign a capacity of size `one` to all the edges between children and beds. After that by running a max flow algorithm on this graph you will find the answer.